# How to toggle visibility in AngularJS based on the text content of the element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Imagine I have the following HTML:

```
<p id="message" ng-show="something"></p>
```

Now during the lifetime of the page `#message` can be filled up with some text message after an AJAX call.

I would like `#message`to toggle itself visible/hidden based on if it contains something or not.

Something like:

```
<p id="message" ng-show="self.text != ''"></p> <!--Not working but you get the idea -->
```

Comment: Instead of jQuery, can you populate the content of the paragraph with an AJAX call from an angular service? If so, you can define the result of the call as $scope.content and use the logic in Feussy's suggestion below.

Comment: Yeah I'm not using jQuery... I used "neutral" likd JS as pseudo-code in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best suggestion would be to bind the content of #message to a scope variable.

```
<p id="message" ng-show="Content != ''">{{Content}}</p>
```

Then you simply need to update the value of $scope.Content to change both the contents of #message and its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Feussy is correct in that binding the `#message` element's content to a scope variable is the correct way to do this.

If for some reason you can't or don't want to bind the content to a variable in your Controller, you can bind the content directly on the element which will get you closer to the syntax that you are looking for.

```
<p id="message" ng-bind="self.text" ng-show="self.text !== ''"></p>
```

[Here is a working example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/PiZbEGfrZM1vKnAoUNoD?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the working example. My true problem was a $scope issue. I'm new to AngularJS and I put the <p> outside the element with ng-controller so it was out of scope...